# Javascript connection with a java applet

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, function

I have a java applet with a main class at Eclipse IDE! I would like to call a function on a javascript. I have a variable for example x and i would like it to give it at the javascript and i want to receive another variable from the javascript for example y on my java applet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to invoke javascript from java Applet [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) and how to invoke java Applet from javascript [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)

Comment: I did it but i can't understand how i could load my javascript, because it has at the JSObject the variable this! And i want to load my own javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Your question a little unclear about exact setup. So I give a couple answers:

1. If you have JavaScript function and want to execute function in Java, maybe this help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino
2. If you have JavaScript run in web browser and web browser also load applet, look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html
3. If you have Java Applet run in Eclipse IDE and JavaScript run in website in other location, you must make Applet provide HTTP(s) server and use XmlHttpRequest in JavaScript for call applet. For this you must use polling from JavaScript to Applet as Applet cannot call function on JavaScript this way, but JavaScript can connect to Applet.

If you have different setup from three mentioned here, please post and maybe we can find better answer.